# Instructions for using the PHP manual (specifically regarding default Boolean values)

Tags: php, conventions, manual

I am writing some script which will utilize cURL, was interested whether I needed to explicitly set various options or whether they are set by default, and thus pulled up http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php.  Often the manually will explicitly state that a given option's default value is true or false, and while `curl_setopt()` does so for many of them, it doesn't do so for others.

It appears that the manual communicates the default value by typing it in bold, but as I have never read that the manual uses this convention, I went off searching for it and was surprised to find that either there is no instructions on how to use the manual or that they are incredible hard to find.

Does the PHP manual indicate default Boolean values by using **bold** font.  Is there any documentation which describes this and other conventions used by the manual?

Comment: By using __bold uppercase font__ manual indicates PHP constants.

Comment: http://doc.php.net/tutorial/ tells how to create the documentation

Comment: @aynber  I would have expected to be there, and specifically in http://doc.php.net/tutorial/style.php or http://doc.php.net/tutorial/faq.php, but it isn't.  The closest I could find is `the <initializer> tag is used to signify the default value ` in the FAQ.

Comment: @u_mulder  I don't think bold uppercase font is reserved only for constants.  The manually uses **TRUE** and FALSE, and TRUE and **FALSE**.

Comment: @user1032531 PHP programmers are expected to recognize those built-in names, so they shouldn't be confused by the inconsistent typography.

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. ("documentation", specifically, although "conventions" and "manual" are useless meta-tags) Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question. Thank you!

Comment: @Mogsdad  Yes, I did read the tag, but wasn't sure about the intent.  And, really I was asking about meta data about the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of the middle column in the option list is **Set `value` to**. This means you're supposed to assume that the value specified in that column is *not* the default, and it's telling you what value you need to provide explicitly to cause the behavior described in the description of the option.

In some cases the default is dependent on other options or the PHP environment. This will be mentioned in description or the **Notes** column.

Comment: Thanks Barmar,  I also looked at phpinfo's output for default values for my configuration, but not much provided for cURL.  Maybe some cURL specific command provides?  Do you know what the meaning of "the <initializer> tag is used to signify the default value" in the FAQ?

Comment: phpinfo just shows the values of php.ini configuration options. The defaults for most of the curl parameters are hard-coded, not configurable options. The FAQ about `<initializer>` is talking about optional function parameters.